# HtmlAgilityPack + Vb + Try get Pic

Tags: vb.net

I have my current code to get the title and the pic.
The title is in one textbox and the pic is in one picturebox.

In my windows form i have :

```
Imports System
Imports System.Xml
Imports HtmlAgilityPack
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections.Generic
```

In the load page for testing i have :

```
Public Class scrapper
    Private Sub scrapper_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'Enable SSL Suppport'
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        'WebPage to Scrapping'
        Dim link As String = "https://www.nextinpact.com/"
        'download page from the link into an HtmlDocument'
        Dim doc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlWeb().Load(link)
        'select the title'
        Dim div As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/section/aside/section/div[2]/div/article[1]/div/div/h3/a")
        'select the image'
        Dim img As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[2]/p[1]/a/img")

        If Not div Is Nothing Then
            TextBox1.Text = div.InnerText.Trim()
        End If

        If Not img Is Nothing Then
            'PictureBox1.Load(img.OuterHtml.Trim())
        End If
        'Test Picturebox2
        PictureBox2.Load("https://cdn2.nextinpact.com/compress/100-76//images/bd/square-linked-media/23647.jpg")

    End Sub

End Class
```

But in in PictureBox1 i cant get the pic.

In Picture2 it's just only for test.

How i can get correctly the pic for Picturebox1 ?

Comment: Which image are you trying to get from that page?

Comment: In the example from the PictureBox2.Load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to pull the same image that is showing in PictureBox2, the XPath on your second SelectSingleNode is incorrect. I would use these instead:

```
'select the title'
Dim div As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//aside[@id='sideBarIndex']//article//div/div/h3/a")
'select the image'
Dim img As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//aside[@id='sideBarIndex']//article//img")
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for the big help.

Answer (score 0):

Well then get simply get URL from  element.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim doc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlWeb().Load("https://www.nextinpact.com/")
    PictureBox1.LoadAsync(doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//aside[@id='sideBarIndex']//img").Attributes("src").Value)
End Sub
```

Like so.

[image]